# can't install apache Kubuntu 14.10

Tags: apache2

```
..$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-data
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom apache2-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-data
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 250 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,194 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  apache2-data apache2
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main apache2-data all 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main apache2 i386 2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.10-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
chumpen@chumpen-Lenovo-G480:~$
```

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get update` first.